# Position of the adverb “auch”

Tags: grammar, word-order, adverb

In the following sentence, where is the right position for the adverb *auch*? Is it possible to place it at the end of the sentence like in English?

> Sie behauptet, dass sie keinen Alkohol mehr trinkt und mit dem Rauchen bald auch aufhören wird.

Comment: As changing the position of *auch* may change the meaning of the sentence: Can you elaborate what you want to convey?

Comment: she ceases alcohol and smoking, i would like to build two sentences using _dass_ and _und_, but i can not determine where to put adverbs

Comment: Apart: Subjunctive or "dass"-clause. That is, either "Sie behauptet, sie trinke keinen Alkohol mehr" or "Sie behauptet, dass sie keinen Alkohol mehr trinkt" — Fixed this as it's not part of the question.

Comment: And more idiomatic: "... und mit dem Rauchen auch bald aufhören wird." - Fixing this, too.

Comment: yes but, i would like to build it in konjunktiv 1 form

Comment: Then "Sie behauptet, sie trinke keinen Alkohol mehr und werde mit dem Rauchen auch bald aufhören." Less common than "dass"-clause, though.

Comment: In respect to your actual question, I see two positions where I would put "auch". Immediately before or after "mit dem Rauchen". I can't quite say why I wouldn't use the word-order you've suggested, although it's technically not wrong at all.

Comment: At the end of the sentence, i.e. *\*und mit dem Rauchen bald aufhören wird auch* is **not** possible.

Comment: by the way is it possible to say: "Alkohol nehmen" or only one can say "Alkohol trinken"

Comment: *Drogen nehmen, Alkohol trinken.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three positions for the *auch* in this sentence, and they all change the meaning slightly.

> ...und auch mit dem Rauchen bald aufhören wird.

puts the emphasis on *smoking/mit dem Rauchen*.

> ...und mit dem Rauchen auch bald aufhören wird.

puts the emphasis on *soon/bald*.

> ...und mit dem Rauchen bald auch aufhören wird.

puts the emphasis on *stop/aufhören*.

At the end of the sentence does not work in German.

Comment: So we put "auch" in front of a word which we want to emphase, yes?

Comment: I don't think that you can put emphasis on "bald" in this sentence, as it doesn't make sense to modify "bald" with "auch". If the sentence were "Sie hört bald mit dem Trinken auf, und auch bald mit dem Rauchen", that's fine. But in the sentence above, it's weird to apply "auch" to "bald". In fact, I don't see a big difference between 1 and 2 ("auch" before/after "mit dem Rauchen"). The slight difference is that in the former case the adverb modifies the whole sentence "mit dem Rauchen aufhören", and the latter case it only modifies the verb. The third sentence is still a bit off, to my mind.

Comment: I think all three are valid, the first being the most common. Concerning the emphasis: I think this may vary... (from person to person, from hour to hour...) (BTW: the emphasize wizard stuff hinders my from upvoting)